# Appending files in node.js on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I tired below code in local works, but not in heroku, anyone know the reason?

```
var mob = req.body.phone + " \n";
fs.appendFile("phone.txt", mob, function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify files in heroku. Use a database instead.